# Creating Accordion Table with Multiple Levels

Tags: javascript, html-table, accordion

I'm trying to create an accordion table with multiple headers that expand to reveal multiple expanding sub-headers.

The HTML I have so far:

```
<tbody>

<tr class="header">
  <th colspan="2">Header</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Sub-Header1</td>
  <td>sub-info</td>
  <td>sub-info</td>
  <td>sub-info</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Sub-Header2</td>
  <td>sub-info</td>
  <td>sub-info</td>
  <td>sub-info</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

Here is the Javascript I have so far:

```
<script>
$('.header').click(function(){
$(this).nextUntil('.header').slideToggle(100, function(){
    });
});
</script>
```

Everything seems to be working so far, EXCEPT, if I expand and collapse the sub-headers and then try to collapse the main header, the sub-headers open back up. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the javascript, but I am unsure how to fix this or proceed.

If anyone can help me fix this code, or show me a new method to creating this accordion table, I would be very appreciative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work, or is this what you are trying to achieve?
JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/d02rm189/1/

Assuming the following structure:

Header

Subheader1
img
some text
link

Subheader2
img
some text
link

When you click on subheader1, the info hides or shows
When you click on subheader2, the info hides or shows
When you click on Header, the info hides or shows

HTML

```
<table>
<tbody>

<tr class='mainheader'>
    <th>Header</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="header">Sub-Header1
    <div class="hideMe">

      <img alt ="yellowpic"  src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2542034/colorPicks/yellow.png">
        <p>sub-info blah blah<p>
        <a>sub-info link</a>

    </div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="header">Sub-Header2
  <div class="hideMe">
    sub-info<br>
    sub-info<br>
    sub-info
  </div></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('.mainheader').on("click", function(){
  $(this).siblings()
         .slideToggle(100);
});

$('.header').on("click", function(){
  $(this).find('.hideMe')
         .slideToggle(100);
});
```

Comment: Oh wait, my only question is, when expanding the sub-headers, how do I get the info. to show up beneath the sub-header and not on the side? @Will

Comment: There's a few different ways to do it ie.  wrap the sub-info in a div would be the most obvious.  Question:  Does all 3 sub info's always show together?

Comment: Yes, under every sub-header, the sub-info will be a picture, a paragraph of text, and a few links. That sub-info. will all be displayed together every time the sub-header is expanded. @Will

Comment: Sorry, sent that last comment before you sent me the jsfiddle! That is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!!! You've really helped me out here. I have one more question (sorry to be so annoying but I hardly know anything about javascript), how do I have the sub-info. start out as hidden? @Will

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61933/discussion-between-will-and-kateg).